# Usage of 'should' versus 'would'

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs

I was wondering if someone could explain the subtle difference between these sentences:

1) Monday should be fine.

2) Monday would be fine.

This is in the context of someone asking if they could help me out on Monday instead of on Sunday. I am a little confused about the difference between the usage of 'should' and 'would' here. Both seem to fit. I personally seem to prefer 'should' but I can't explain why. Any help *w*ould be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: *should* indicates that according to the information you have now - Monday will be fine (but only if you're knowledge about the future is correct). *would* indicates that Monday will be/is fine.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I see what you're saying. Is there a good reference (example or explanation) for this? I can't get people to agree on whether 'should' or 'would' conveys doubt.

Comment: Based on the responses, I think there are the usual ways to go about solving this:
1) Seeing examples of historical usage 
2) Seeing examples of current usage 
3) Cite the grammar book. 
I think this use of 'should' in this case is a little informal and doesn't correspond to the usual 'conditional obligation'. So 1 and 2 should be the way to go. I'll see if I can dig up something.

Comment: (Also, I can't up-vote since I don't have enough rep yet :-/)

Comment: I think you can upvote, but only on your own questions! At least, I think so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Monday should be fine.
>
> 2) Monday would be fine.

*Should* in sentence 1 is not the same use of *should* that we find in examples such as:

- What should I do?
- You should apologise.
- You should eat five portions of fruit and vegetables every day.

The sentences above are asking for advice or giving advice. We can think of advice here like a form of weak obligation. If someone gives us advice, there is some pressure on us to do that thing - but we don't *have to* do it - it is our decision. This kind of meaning, when we talk about *obligation* and *permission*, is called  *DEONTIC* modality.

Sentence 1 is *NOT* about deontic modality. This type of *should* is about *EPISTEMIC* modality. Epistemic modality is about knowledge and belief. Think about the following sentences:

- It might be in box 3.
- It should be in box 3.
- It must be in box 3.

The first example above shows that the speaker has a weak belief that it is in box 3. The second sentence shows that the speaker has a fairly strong belief that it is box 3, but she's not certain. The last example shows that the speaker is certain that it is in box 3.

In the Original Poster's example, (1) indicates that the speaker has a strong conviction, a strong belief, that Monday will be fine. Of course this is the technical meaning of what they are saying. The effect of saying this sentence is probably "Yes, choose Monday".

*Would* in sentence (2) indicates a logical result of choosing Monday. The sentence is like the last part of a conditional:

- If you chose Monday, Monday would be fine.

Here the speaker is definite about the fact that the result of choosing Monday is it's being fine. They aren't indicating any doubt about it. Again the effect in the conversation is probably "Yes, choose Monday".

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Yes, that helps. It's wikiable too:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality

Comment: @Salmonstrikes Shall I add that to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Monday should be fine = the other persons prefers Monday, or agrees Monday is a good change. 
Monday would be fine = Monday also fits her/his interest, though Sunday may still be a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for your responses lnjuanj and Araucaria.
I think that the crux of the matter here, based on the responses, is that one of the words conveys doubt and the other certainty. I don't see a consensus, though. Does anyone have a reference?

Comment: This just comes from the usage of modal verbs. *Should* states conditional obligation, while *would* states possibility.

Answer (score 0):

While both the sentences are grammatically fine, the subtlety lies in *would* and *should*. As ***compared to*** 'would', 'should' is firmer. Think of an example `I would do it` and `I should do it`.

Having said that, if you tell *Monday should be fine*, it gives a little flair of *ordering* someone as in *The work **should** be done on Monday*. On the other hand, *Monday would be fine* shows probability or in better words a 'mutually understood' day which I think is your intention.